# Content Type Localization

Tags: content-type, localization

I am trying to localize a SharePoint 2013 Content Type.

I created a new Content Type in Visual Studio and Added a few Sitecolumns to it.
I also added a Feature Resource file and linked the Displaynames of the Sitecolums to Resources like: $Resource:Column1.

When I deploy the Solution to the SharePoint everything seems fine. When I look at the Sitecolumns and the content Type in the Site Settings they localize fine. Also a list, which uses the content Type is localized correctly. But The New/Edit/...Forms of the the list do not localize. They use the language which was set when the Feature with the Content Type was acitvated.

When I reactivate the feature with a different language set, then the dialogs change the language, but not when I just change my browser language and hit F5, like the rest of the SharePoint does.

Does anybody know this Problem? Am I doing something wrong? This cannot be the meant behavior of SharePoint.

best regards
Alex